# Solving a linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following equation?

$\frac {d^2x} {dt^2} = (a_1 x + b_1) cos (\omega t + \phi) + (a_2 x + b_2)$

$a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ are real coefficients; $x (0)$ and $\frac {dx} {dt} (0)$ are given.

Comment: Have you solved non-homogeneous odes before?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform